# Show 'insertion' and 'lastName' in listfield ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I only have 1 row now in my listfield with 'FirstName' but I need to have 2 other rows in the listfield.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="FirstName" DataValueField="Insertion"></asp:ListBox>
```

Only `DataTextField="FirstName"` is showing but i need FirstName, Insertion and LasName to show in the listfield

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not achieve that in the normal way, you should customised the returned data in the returned query ex:  `select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName from table` then set `DataTextField = "FullName"`